# Inverse search from Okular to TexMaker

Tags: latex, pdflatex, texmaker, okular

I am trying to properly set up the inverse search function from my compiled .pdf back to the .tex file.

On the TexMaker side, the "Configure Texmaker" field for PdfLatex writes

`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

The "External Viewer" field writes

`okular %.pdf --unique`

On the Okular side, the "Configure Okular" field for Editor currently writes

`Editor: Custom Text Editor`

`texmaker --line %l --column %c`

The Shift+left click does not work how it used to, with other editors. I am on "Browse" mode. Does anyone know how to fix this? I would also like to set up forward search, but the inverse one is really what matters now.

PS. I am using Ubuntu and Windows, on different machines, same issue.

Update: it looks like when I am using, say,

`texmaker -line %l -column %c`

or similar variations, and then shift+left click, nothing happens but when I go to the .tex file the cursor is at the right spot! So the only thing that does not work is the automatic opening of the .tex file.